# How to configure Maven multi module dependency on sub project with different packaging

Tags: java, maven, war, multi-module

I have 2 maven projects: one is a rest service with a *WAR packaging* (rest), the other one is a module to access database with a *jar packaging* (service).

In the pom of the rest module I add the dependency with service as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

However I'm getting this error:

> Project 'rest' is missing required library:
>        'C:\Users\user.m2\repository\project\service\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

I'm still developping the service module, so  it can't be in .m2 library. How can I connect this two modules. Is there any way that I can access to my service functions in the `@RestController` classes?

EDIT:
My project directory structure is

```
Rest
  |--- pom.xml

Service
  |--- pom.xml
```

Both are independent projects.

Running `mvn clean package install` on service project works, but, is there any way to make maven read my snapshoot version?

Comment: I guess you are having multi module build. show us your project directory structure

Comment: and also the `pom.xml` from the service and rest module along with the parent `pom.xml`

Comment: Did you build service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'? I suggest you perform "mvn clean package install" for that(service project) project first and then build war.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have your multi module projects works together you need to add them with parent project. Dont worry all your modular projects can be independent and build separately. Say for your case your parent project directory should be like

```
parent
  |-- pom.xml
  rest
     |--- pom.xml  
  service
     |--- pom.xml
```

And in your **top level** or **parent** POM you will tell maven about all your sub module projects like

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

       <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>your.groudid</groupId>
       <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <modules>
            <module>rest</module>
            <module>service</module>
        </modules>
    </project>
```

And in your **service** module `pom.xml` have this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>your.groudid</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<name>service</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

It will tell maven that it has a parent module and its needed to be build as a jar with the concerning artifact-id

Now you can tell maven that your **rest** module has a dependecy of **service** module just as like other dependecies. Follow this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>your.groudid</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<name>rest</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
   ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>your.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

**Note:** For better understanding you can read this short [Maven Multi Module Project](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/) article. And also this github [repository](https://github.com/jamesward/maven-multi-module-example) that has a concise example about this.

Comment: My two projects live in different repositories so they aren't really in the same folder hierarchy.  Is there any way to connect them like this.  I could put the parent pom four or five levels up in the folder in the directory that holds the two repositories but I don't think Maven is designed for that.